# Layer is hidden by another layer

Tags: css

I have a problem, I suppose, with z-index. I set z-index:999999...

```
z-Index:9999999!important;
```

so very big value but layer keeps to be overlaid. To replicate this issue go http://copy.barchick.com/calendar/ and try to expand pressing red `...` on THU 1, then press on SUN 4 red '...' or some other and those other will display correctly but not on THU 1 even if all is the same for all boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `I` in the z-index property is lowercase.  Also make sure you set position relative or absolute on the element.

```
z-index:9999999 !important;
```